# Is it possible to get access to the Manifest when initialising a val inside a trait that uses generics?

Tags: scala, manifest, implicit

What I'm trying to do (this is a simplified example, but contains all I need)

```
trait MyTrait[T] {

  val name = Somefunction(simpleName)

  def simpleName(implicit m:Manifest[T]) = m.erasure.getSimpleName

}
```

But I get a "No Manifest available for T" compiler error on the val initialisation at simpleName.

doing

```
val name = Somefunction(implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.getSimpleName)
```

does the same

Somefunction returns a object that is expensive to create, so I only want to create it once.

The only way I got this to work is by using a function that checks if the object has already been created and if so then just return it else create it first and then return it.

**EDIT -- added example of how I can get it to work**

example

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  var n:MyClass = null
  def name(implicit m:Manifest[T]) = {
    if(n == null) n = Somefunction(implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.getSimpleName)
    n
  }
}
```

Comment: The example is not at all equivalent to your original desire; because  you have to call the `name` method on an instance of the `trait`

Comment: ALso this will create an instance of Manifest[T] every time you call `name`, although you only need it once.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes The `name` method gets called from other methods inside the trait. The object that gets extended with the trait is an empty object.

@drexin Yes, that is why I was looking for a way to initialise a `val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare the type parameter of a `trait` as having a `Manifest` context-bound because it is equivalent to requiring a constructor parameter (which a trait cannot have). I understand that allowing this is planned for some future version of scala.

Furthermore, a `val` cannot have parameters, so it is simply not possible to instantiate a `val` dependent on an instance of `Manifest[T]` that I can see. But you have said you have got this to work: how?

Comment: I stand by what I said regarding your example; i.e. that there is no way of defining a `val` which is dependent on `Manifest[T]`. Not only have you had to declare it a `var`, but the `var` can only be initialized by calling a method on an *instance* of your trait. That is, the initialization of the value cannot be purely encapsulated within the trait.